# Can't get DOMRect object within Webdriver-io (js) test

Tags: javascript, dom, webdriver-io

I need to get the coordinates of an element on a web page using the .getBoundingClientRect() function. When I solved this problem a year ago, I did it like this:

```
browser.executeScript('window.document.querySelector("div.myDiagramDiv canvas").getBoundingClientRect();', [])
```

**Note**: I perform this operation as part of writing an automated test on Webdriver-io, so the window object is not available, and I have to use browser.executeScript.

Now, a year later, I went back to my task and the above code returns an empty object.

I tried to debug this code within the test and in the browser console. The result is as follows:

**Webdriver-io test code:**

```
a = browser.executeScript('window.document.querySelector("div.myDiagramDiv canvas")', [])
console.log(a) # output : { 'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': 'ELEMENT-40' }
b = browser.executeScript('window.document.querySelector("div.myDiagramDiv canvas").getBoundingClientRect();', [])
console.log(b) # output : {}
```

**Debug in the browser console**

```
a = window.document.querySelector("div.my_diagram_div canvas")
# output : <canvas tabindex="0" style="position: absolute; top:…t: 435px; cursor: auto;" width="1519" height="435">
b = a.getBoundingClientRect()
# output : DOMRect { x: 158.5, y: 132, width: 1519, height: 435, top: 132, right: 1677.5, bottom: 567, left: 158.5 }
```

Browser console screen:
[image]

Why, within the framework of the test, I can not get the DOMRect object, but in the browser console it turns out?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will work in this way:

```js
a = browser.execute('window.document.querySelector("div.myDiagramDiv canvas")')
b = browser.execute((a) => {
  return a.getBoundingClientRect();
}, a);
```